# C# NAudio Volume

Tags: c#, volume, naudio

As title, I just searched very thoroughly on the web, still not having an answer.
I'm working with `WaveChannel32`  like this : `WaveChannel32 volumeStream` and setting the volume like : `volumeStream.Volume`, the default value is 1 but if it increase, the volume increase only once, so I suspect is it more like a toggle than a volume control. If I am right, so how to control the volume？ 
*Refer to http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3*

Comment: Have you checked the NAudio samples? There are at least two that also allow you to change the volumen - and they work ;-)

Comment: samples? which samples you mean, can you give a link?

Comment: Well, those from the [download page of the project](http://naudio.codeplex.com/releases/view/96875)? Download "Demo Apps" if you want the binaries, "Source" if you want the source - this will download the complete NAudio source including samples.

Comment: nope, can't find any things there =(

Comment: Nonsense. Did you even have a look? If so, where did you look?

Comment: I download the demo apps, there's a control which is working, but without any code, then I searched the source code, not seeing anything referring to WaveChannel32.  Or maybe I searched the wrong way..

Comment: That's really poor... I needed al of 30 seconds to find a sample... You should work on your problem solving skills! NAudio-Source\NAudioDemo\SimplePlaybackDemo\SimplePlaybackPanel.cs

Answer (score 2):

The `Volume` property is a multiplier. So 1 means keep the volume the same, 0 means silence. 0.5 would make it quieter, 2.0 would double the amplitude of each sample etc. Note that if you increase this value above 1 there is the chance that you will clip your audio later when you play it or convert it back to a WAV file.